# Raspberry vs arduino i2c communication

Tags: raspbian, python, i2c, arduino

i used to use arduino as a i2c communication device but i'm changing to raspberry and i have a question about how to send and receive data from raspberry to my device

the device in question is a pressure and temperature sensor, the sensor address is 0x78

i need to send 0xAC, wait some time and then request 6 bytes

the arduino code is the following:

```
Wire.beginTransmission(0x78);
    Wire.write(0xAC);
    Wire.endTransmission();
    delay(50); 
    

    Wire.requestFrom(0x78, 6);        // request 6 bytes 

    if (Wire.available() == 6) {        // read 6 bytes :status, BridgeDat1, BridgeDat2, BridgeDat3, TempDat1, TempDat2
      data[0] = Wire.read();  //status
      data[1] = Wire.read();  //BridgeDat1
      data[2] = Wire.read();  //BridgeDat2
      data[3] = Wire.read();  //BridgeDat3
      data[4] = Wire.read();  //TempDat1
      data[5] = Wire.read();  //TempDat2
    }
```

my question is, how to do that in python ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some methods using my Python modules.

You can also use the Python smbus module.

[pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html)

```py
import time
import pigpio

pi = pigpio.pi()

h = pi.i2c_open(1, 0x78)

pi.i2c_write_device(h, [0xAC])
time.sleep(0.05)
(b, d) = pi.i2c_read_device(h, 6)

print(d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5])

pi.i2c_close(h)

pi.stop()
```

[rgpio](http://abyz.me.uk/lg/py_rgpio.html)

```py
import time
import rgpio

sbc = rgpio.sbc()

h = sbc.i2c_open(1, 0x78)

sbc.i2c_write_device(h, [0xAC])
time.sleep(0.05)
(b, d) = sbc.i2c_read_device(h, 6)

print(d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5])

sbc.i2c_close(h)

sbc.stop()
```

[lgpio](http://abyz.me.uk/lg/py_lgpio.html)

```py
import time
import lgpio as sbc

h = sbc.i2c_open(1, 0x78)

sbc.i2c_write_device(h, [0xAC])
time.sleep(0.05)
(b, d) = sbc.i2c_read_device(h, 6)

print(d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5])

sbc.i2c_close(h)
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thanks so much